# Writing a C++ recursive function that computes and displays the product of the first n doubles in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void countDown(int n);
double computeProduct(const double anArray[], int n);

int main()
{
    //Stand alone test of computeProduct function.

    double Array[10] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0};
    computeProduct(Array, 4);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");



    return 0;
}
double computeProduct(const double anArray[], int n)
{

    if (n == 1) {

        return anArray[0];

    }
    else {

        cout << anArray[n-1] * computeProduct(anArray, n-1);    

    }
}
```

This should work, but for some reason when I run the program the console returns:
2-nan(ind)-nan(ind)
Press any key to continue...

I have never seen -nan(ind) before and have no idea what to do or what I did.
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: why don't you focus on writing a recursive function which compute the product and merely display its result ?

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to step through your code line by line and *watch* values of variables.  Often, debugging your program is faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect or debug your program for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your function computeProduct() works only when n = 1. Otherwise, it returns an undefined value. 
Your compiler probably gave you a warning such as "Not all control paths return a value".

One way to fix this is adding an additional variable:

```
 double computeProduct(const double anArray[], int n)
 {                
     double product = 0.0; 

     if (n == 1) {                        
         product = anArray[0];                        
     }
     else {
         product = anArray[n-1] * computeProduct(anArray, n-1);                        
     }                
     //add your debug information here ...
     cout << "return value for index n = " << n << " is " << product;

     return product ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote doesnt have an explicit return value if n != 1. This is undefined behavior, which in your case means the value effectively returned is garbage.

A simple modification to your program does the trick. Note that you need to account for sizes smaller than 1 otherwise you are going to have a segfault.

```
double computeProduct(const double anArray[], int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0.0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return anArray[0];
    }
    else {
        return anArray[n-1] * computeProduct(anArray, n-1);    
    }
}
...
cout << computeProduct(Array, 4)<< endl;
```

The best recursive function is broken in two, one using an accumulator, and the other which provide the desired interface :

```
double computeProductAcc(const double anArray[], int n, double acc)
{
    if (n <= 0) {
        return acc;
    } else {
        return  computeProductAcc(anArray, n-1, anArray[n-1] * acc); 
    }
}

double computeProduct(const double anArray[], int arraySize, int n) 
{
    if(n > arraySize || n <= 0) {
      return 0.0
    }
    return computeProductAcc(anArray, n, 1.0)
}
```

Comment: note that I assume here that the array has at least n elements.